# How do I see the file transfer speed in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, file-transfer, speed, data-transfer

I just noticed that Windows 7 does not display the actual data transfer speed when copying/moving a file from one directory/disk to another. All it shows is a progress bar and their guess as to the amount of time remaining to complete.

On my Windows 8 machine, these same operations will show the actual data transfer speed in MB/s that the operation is happening at.

Is there a way to see this information in Win7?

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed, this is a [new Feature since Windows 8](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/b8/2011/08/23/improving-our-file-management-basics-copy-move-rename-and-delete/)

So, for Windows 7, you need 3rd party tools like [TeraCopy](http://www.codesector.com/teracopy)

[image]

which replace the copy/move/delete dialog and display the data.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, this feature is built into Windows 7, at least Home Premium and above have it, not sure about below editions.

When your copy dialog is open, it should have a `More details` button in the bottom left. Clicking that will show you what you are looking for, but not as nicely as 8 and above do:

[image: Copy dialog with details exposed]

Comment: yea, but I think he means the history graph wich is new since Win8, but without any reaction of the user we must speculate what he asks

Comment: It doesn't show the actual data transfer speed but show average speed. If, for example, transfer will stop for a minute, it will show decreasing numbers instead of 0.